# draw on canvas in different device has different smoothness

Tags: android

In my application i am used canvas to draw a letter.
my code is working .

But my problem is smoothness in different devices.

I am put screen short

1)screen short take from samsung tab 2 7 inch
[image]

[image]

2) screen short take from google nexus 7 inch.

What is the problem in samsung device why smoothness not working .

I am also download such type of drawing application but not properly working in samsung device.

Please help me .

Below code is used for paint

```
class MyTView extends View {
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
        public MyTView(Context c) {
            super(c);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(),
                display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        // set canvas background color white
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        // paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mCanvas.drawPaint(paint);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        }

        public MyTView(Context c, AttributeSet atrs ) {     
            super(c, atrs);     

            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            //    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mPath = new Path();     
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);


        } 




        public MyTView(Context c,Bitmap bmp ) {     
            super(c);    
             mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
             mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
             mPath = new Path();     
             mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
             mCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0,null);
       } 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mTPaint); // ORIGINAL
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); // ORIGINAL
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mTPaint);
        }



        public void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            arrXY.clear();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
            arrXY.add(new XYBean(x, y)); 
        }

        public void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            arrXY.add(new XYBean(x, y));
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {

            btn_replay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_blue);
            btn_replay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


            System.out.println("--- touch up event ------");
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
              // commit the path to our offscreen
             mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mTPaint);
             mPath.reset();


             getScreenCap(drawLayout);



        }


           // mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            ++count;
            isSet = false;
            //arrXY.clear();
            System.out.println("After clearing the arrXY: "+arrXY.size());
            isStart = true;





            postInvalidate();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mTPaint); // edited by shreyash
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mTPaint); // edited by shreyash
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                   // arrXY.clear();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your smoothing code?

Comment: i think there is problem in samsung modified ANDROID OS

Comment: @JatinPatel how to solve my problem.

Comment: @Telthien : i am put my drawing code please check it.